# Export to excel from SQL Server 2000 using Query Analyzer code

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, query-analyzer

What's the easiest way to export data to excel from SQL Server 2000.

I want to do this from commands I can type into query analyzer.

I want the column names to appear in row 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manual copy and paste is the only way to do exactly what you're asking. Query Analyzer can include the column names when you copy the results, but I think you may have to enable that somewhere in the options first (it's been a while since I used it).

Other alternatives are:

1. Write your own script or program to convert a result set into a .CSV or .XLS file
2. Use a DTS package to export to Excel
3. Use bcp.exe (but it doesn't include column names, so you have to [kludge](http://dbaspot.com/forums/sqlserver-programming/391006-bcp-out-including-column-question.html) it)
4. Use a linked server to a blank Excel sheet and INSERT the data

Generally speaking, you cannot export data from MSSQL to a flat file using pure TSQL, because TSQL cannot manipulate anything outside the database (using a linked server is sort of cheating). So you usually need to use some sort of client application anyway, whether it's bcp.exe, dtswiz.exe or your own program.

And as a final comment, MSSQL 2000 is no longer supported (unless your company has an extended maintenance agreement) so you may want to look into upgrading at some point.

Comment: The linked server was the way to go, I didn't rule out cheating in my question :-)

Comment: This answer is incorrect.

In particular, these assertions are false:

"Manual copy and paste is the only way to do exactly what you're asking...

Other alternatives are:

Write your own script or program to convert a result set into a .CSV or .XLS file
...
Generally speaking, you cannot export data from MSSQL to a flat file using pure TSQL, because..."

As Joe Stefanelli's answer below shows, Query Analyzer options can *easily* be changed to output query results to a .csv file. You do not, in fact, need your own script or "kludge" program to accomplish this.

Answer (score 6):

In Query Analyzer, go to the Tools -> Options menu. On the Results tab, choose to send your output to a CSV file and select the "Print column headers" option. The CSV will open in Excel and you can then save it as a .XLS/.XLSX

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this clear, easy, and *correct* answer.