# Exporting a table from SQL Server 2008 R2 to a file WITHOUT external tools

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to export a table from SQL Server 2008 R2 to a file. The problem is that I don't have bcp (nor can I install it or anything else) and am not able to run xpcmdshell. Anyone have any ideas on how this could be done without those permissions/tools? (I would like to have this happen on some automated basis preferably)

Comment: no, it has something called "Query Analyzer" and some proprietary sql tool that is of no use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the results pane, click the top-left cell to highlight all the records, and then right-click the top-left cell and click "Save Results As". One of the export options is CSV.

You can also use a command like this too:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=c:\Test.xls;','SELECT productid, price FROM dbo.product')
```

Lastly, you can look into using SSIS (replaced DTS) for data exports. Here is a link to a tutorial: http://www.accelebrate.com/sql_training/ssis_2008_tutorial.htm

Answer (score 2):

I'm usually using Copy/Paste from SSMS `Results Pane` to `Excel`

[image]

---

**OR**

you can right click on database in the `Object Explorer` and select `Database->Tasks->Export Data`. An `SQL Server Import and Export Wizard` dialog opens and you will be able to export data from any table or query to the file or another destination.

---

**OR**

you can use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) - awesome, simlpe and free tool (I really love it) that doesn't require installation

[image]

Comment: why? It is really cool and you can install it for free http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8961

Answer (score 1):

If you have SQL Server 2012 you could add File Tables to your database.  Thus you could use SQL Agent to schedule a simple stored proc to update the file table when desired.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144.aspx#Description

Answer (score 1):

> it has something called "Query Analyzer"

Query Analyzer (isqlw.exe) is the SQL 2000, pre-SSMS, query tool. A very fine tool. Among other things, is capable of exporting query results to a file. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3769766/105929:

> go to the Tools -> Options menu. On the Results tab, choose to send your output to a CSV file and select the "Print column headers" option.

Comment: This is good except I would like to have this as an automated process without my intervention that exports tables to a file.